# The "CouldBe" logic for regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a credit card validator based on the regex provided at http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html

I know that applying the regex can tell me a certain sequence of number "Matches" or "Does Not" match. But I am not sure how to test a sub-sequence that "Could leading to a match".

For example:
   for the regex `^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$`, which I use for testing master card,
   the sequence "54" could lead to a matching master card, but "56" will fail. Applying 
`/^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$/.test` will not work for this case because it only matches the full sequence.

How do I achieve this "Match start" logic with regex in javascript?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you saying you want to test with `/^5[1-5]/` prior to testing with `/^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$/`?

Comment: I would like to use /^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$/ to test a sub-sequence. I don't want to write a different regex for every "keyup" event.

Comment: In some ways, the request seems very valid, but a part of me thinks that this wouldn't be a possible feature in Regex libraries without breaking some aspect of the language. Like LastCoder said, it's definitely possible to accomplish this *IF* you are willing to do some customization and regex recoding for each field.

Comment: This is a similar problem to one in [a question I asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773543/javascript-regex-library-with-incremental-testing). I wasn't able to find a library that does incremental testing. It would be awesome if someone were to build one.

Comment: Logically, "could lead to a match" implies that what is currently in the box matches some subsequence of the full match requirements.  So `/^5?[1-5]?[0-9]{0,14}$/` is probably the most generic that you can get for "could lead to a match", but the example "56" that you gave will also match this pattern, so it comes down to a decision between `/^5?[1-5]?[0-9]{0,14}$/` which will include "56" and `/^5[1-5][0-9]{0,14}$/` which will not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have 2 RegExp, one that does the final validation (like on form submit and on blur) and one that does a check while the box is still being edited.

http://jsfiddle.net/E6sdX/

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="txtCC">
```

JS

```
function finalCheck() {
    if(/^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$/.test(this.value)) {
        this.style.color = "green";
    } else {
        this.style.color = "red";
    }
}
function weakCheck() {
    if(/^5[1-5][0-9]{0,14}$/.test(this.value)) {
        this.style.color = "green";
    } else {
        this.style.color = "red";
    }
}
var tb = document.getElementById("txtCC");
tb.onblur = finalCheck;
tb.onkeyup = weakCheck
```

**Edit** Notice that the RegExp in the weakCheck function has {0,14} instead of {14}. I'll leave the 5[1-5] part up to you.

Comment: Why even bother using `[0-9]{0,14}`? You're not using the match for anything, and they're technically optional.

Comment: @h2ooooooo - so if someone types in "5 5 Z z ! @ #" before they trigger the onblur event they will know that it's incorrect.

Comment: Ah fair enough, didn't see that you had end anchor.